# CSS inline style for colour not applied to text in email template in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, html, css, email, laravel-4

I am setting up Laravel 4.2 to send emails. I have an email template ready for the message. The data input for the emails are stored in an array. However, if I pass a parameter for example $variable, the style are only applied to part of the text.

app/view/email.blade.php

```
//let's say $variable = 'This'

<td align="center" 
class="heading1" 
style="display:block!important; 
max-width:654px!important; 
margin:0 auto!important; 
clear:both!important; 
font-family:&#39;Helvetica Neue&#39;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
color:#212121; 
font-size: 28px;">
<strong> {{ $variable }} <br> is some text. </strong></td>
```

As shown above,  the output should be "This is some text.". However, the colour only apply to the text before the < br > and not entire text. Any ideas what may have gone wrong?

Example output:

```
This <-- colour #212121 is applied
is some text <-- text turned purple (should be #212121).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is probably really basic, and you've probably already tried it, but have you got a conflicting style on the `<strong>` tag? So, the color #212121 is being overridden?

For example, have you tried putting the important tag on the color inline? Just to see if it makes a difference. I know this doesn't account for why the first piece of text is the right color, it's just a thought.

:)

Comment: actually the text works if it's pure text. But, if the variable is passed from an array, the colour of the text just changes.

Comment: Is it just text that is being passed on the variable?

Comment: for some reason it solved the problem. The template was prepared by the designer so I didn't really think the template would be a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apply css in `<strong>` tag like as:

```
<strong style="color:#212121;"> This <br> is some text. </strong>
```